# Pattern recognition problem: if $2 \star 8 \star 8 = 161642\dots$ then M=?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

The following sequence was given to me by one of my friend:

> $$\color{red}{2 \star 8 \star 8 = 161642}$$
>   $$\color{blue}{4 \star 9 \star 7 = 362843}$$
>   $$\color{red}{7 \star 5 \star 9 = 356344}$$
>   $$\color{blue}{9 \star 6 \star 8 = 547245}$$
>   $$\color{red}{5 \star 7 \star 9 = 354546}$$
>   $$\color{blue}{3 \star 9 \star 9 = 272748}$$
>   $$\color{red}{4 \star 8 \star 9 = \text{M}}$$
>   $\color{red}{\text{M}}$ = ?

**My Thoughts**:

The first two digits of R.H.S can be found by $a.b$ , where L.H.S = $a \star b \star c$ ,
i.e, For 1st relation: $2.8=16 = 1^{st}$ two digits of $\color{green}{16}1642$

Similarly,the second two digits of R.H.S can be found by $a.c$ , where L.H.S = $a \star b \star c$ ,
i.e, For 2nd relation: $4.7=28 = 2^{nd} $ two digits of $36 \color{green}{28}43$

$$\implies M= 3236 \, \_ \, \_$$

How do I find the $3^{rd}$ two digits of R.H.S?

Comment: Hi, @Suresh, and welcome to PSE! When you post someone else's puzzle on the site, please always attribute the puzzle to the original creator. (Mentioning the book's and/or creator's name is usually enough.) Thanks, and happy puzzling!

Comment: @Bass actually i don't know it's creator; one of my friend has given this question; so how would i mention its creator name? :(

Comment: I tried googling the numbers, but the only match other than this page is [a Korean forum post](http://www.slrclub.com/bbs/vx2.php?id=free&no=36549143) from last August.

Comment: @Suresh You don't have to exhaustively search to find *the* original source if it's not readily available, but if it's not your original content then you should note where *you* found it.  ("Source: sent to me by a friend" is acceptable, if that's honestly the best you can do.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last pair of digits is given by the formula:

> $a+2b+3c$

so for $4*8*9$ we get

> $4+16+27=47$

Answer (score 2):

M=

> $323647$

because

> the first four digits are as you give. The fifth digit is $4$. The final digit is $1$+the lowest digit in the opening local sequence that hasn't already been used by the previous entries in the global sequence. In this case $2+1=3,3+1=4$ and $4+1=5$ have already been used previously, leaving $6+1=7$ as the last digit.
>
>  For example, the lowest digit in $16164$ is $1$, so the last digit is $1+1=2$. The lowest digit in $36284$ is $2$, so last digit is $3$. The lowest digit in $54724$ is $2$, but $3$ has already been used, so we try with the next lowest digit, $4$, to give the last digit as $5$.

Comment: Yeah, always with the sample size :-/. This seems to be a valid solution, but I think Jaap's must be the intended one, because it can be applied to any three numbers without the full knowledge of the other samples. +1ing anyway.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand your reason for the $6^{th}$ digit , i.e, "the lowest digit in the opening local sequence that hasn't already been used by the previous entries in the global sequence." Can you please explain this statement in details...

Comment: @Suresh; I've added an explanation into my post.